# SDI or HDMI to USB3 interface with 16 audio channel support

Tags: audio, hdmi, sdi, usb, embedding

I'm looking to take a video feed and multiple audio channels into a Windows laptop. The audio channels are essentially live event commentary in various languages, which the laptop will then stream to different Youtube channels. The production team embeds all 16 audio feeds onto an SDI cable alongwith the video feed and essentially gives me just one SDI cable to do what I have to do.

Blackmagic Ultrastudio Mini does a good job getting 16 embedded audio channels in, but it has a thunderbolt interface, which is not too common among Windows laptops.

I've got a Magewell USB Capture SDI plus, but that only brings in 2 audio channels embedded in the SDI.

Are there any alternatives that are capable of pulling in all 16 embedded audio channels in the SDI?

Comment: Contact some vendors directly. (eg BlackMagicDesign)